# Visual Studio 2019 - WPF .Net Framework 4.8 - Adding SQLite with ADO.NET

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework, ado.net, visual-studio-2019, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to add SQLite with ADO.Net, and I am really struggling with it.
This is the packages I have installed:

- Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework 1.0.115
- System.Data.SQLite 1.0.115
- System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.115
- System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.115
- System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.115
- EntityFramework 6.4.4

  I have created the db using [dbBrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org) and placed it within the app. 
  Whatever I do, I just can't seem to get the connection:

  [image]

  I have look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1056400/Setting-up-SQLite-and-Entity-Framework-Code-First), however it is 6 years old.

  I have also tried [this](https://sodeve.net/2021/10/solved-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-system-data-sqlite-ef6-is-either-not-registered-in-the-machine-or-application-config-file-or-could-not-be-loaded-see-the-inner-exception-for-det/), but without success.

  On the system.data.sqlite website, it is mentioned: "The setup packages, which contain the Design-Time Components for Visual Studio are no longer officially supported". So how?

What am I missing? How do we use sqlite with ado.net in vs2019?

Comment: install [DDEX provider](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider)

Comment: "The setup packages, which contain the Design-Time Components for Visual Studio are no longer officially supported" meaning "Download the latest sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.xxx.0.exe" is no longer valid. I believe this was due to a change in vs2019 in August (?)

Comment: install this extension: https://www.vsixgallery.com/extension/41521019-e4c7-480c-8ea8-fc4a2c6f50aa

Comment: You were correct. The mistake I was doing was to install the 64-bit version, while the 32 is required for visual studio. Thanks MagicAndre.

Comment: ok, post an answer what you did in detail to help others

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Sqlite with ado.net on a WPF .NET Framework project, is relatively easy if you know the steps.
Thanks to MagicAndre for providing guidance. Here we go:

1 - Install the toolbox from [here](https://www.vsixgallery.com/extension/41521019-e4c7-480c-8ea8-fc4a2c6f50aa). This is straight forward.

2 - Install GAC from [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads-unsup.wiki). Now here is where I was failing. I was
installing the 64-bit package only, while the 32 is needed for the GAC. So download and install:

- sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.115.0.exe
- sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.115.0.exe 
  When installing the 32-bit package, be careful to check as per below image: 
  [image]

3 - If you haven’t created your db, download DB Browser from [here](https://sqlitebrowser.org). Create your db, place a copy within your project, and include it. You can set the build action to content if you are going to distribute the app later.

4 - Create a solution in visual studio, and nugget install:
System.Data.SQLite: This will auto install the other 4 packages as well as
EntityFramework

5 - In visual studio, go to your server explorer, right click Data connections, add connection

Change your data source to: SQLite Provider (Simple for EF6 by ErikEJ) (SQLite Provider (Simple for EF6 by ErikEJ))

A new window will open
The connectionString line at the top would be in this format:
Data source="C:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\sqlite\sqlite\demo.db";Version=3;
Data source=path;Version=3;
[image]
Click ok and the connection will appear in server explorer.

6 - ADO.NET:
Right click solution, add, add new item. Go to Data and select ado.net
EF Designer from database (database first) and your connection should appear:
[image]
Click next, select all tables required, and click finish. Your edmx file will then be prepared and opened.

7 - Within your app.config entityFramework section, the following lines should be there:

```
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
```

Below should be a system.data section as:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Finally, If you are going to use Foreign keys, add:

```
Foreign Key Constraints=On;
```

between the path and the version of the connection string, in the app.config file.

I think that's about it to get started. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have a .net6 application running the latest version of the 'sqlite-net-pcl' NuGet, but had issues running the same NuGet in 4.8 framework.

I found out the the only version that worked for me was 'sqlite-net-pcl' version 1.7.335 then had to update the 'SQLitePCLRaw' depencies to 2.0.4

[my SQLite NuGet's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJQR0.png)

Comment: This combination works here too:  4.8 framework + sqlite-net-pcl 1.7.335  + update SQLitePCLRaw depencies to 2.0.4. Tks!